# execute interactive command line form java application

Tags: command, interactive

How I can run/execute interactive command line from the java application or java class or program using eclipse?

anything that will help me in order to achieve this!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check out the Java tutorials! 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Or try searching for "execute system commands in java" in your favorite search engine. This should give you plenty to read.